# Leitura de Arquivo em java percorrendo linha especifica se existir

Tags: java

Estou lendo arquivo em java que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
nomedapessoa;data de nascimentodependente1+tipodependente2+tipodependenteN+tipo
```

Podendo ter nenhum, um ou vários dependentes em cada linha do arquivo. O problema é que não consigo percorrer todos os dependentes de uma linha se existir.

```
    if(linha.length() > 36) {
            // se linha maior que 36 possui dependentes
            String dependentes = linha.substring(36);
            // variavel dependentes recebe restante da linha com todos os dependentes 
            String tip = "01"+"02"+"03";        
            String[] vetor = dependentes.split (tip);
            //essa vetor serve para separar os dependentes

            String nomedep = "";
            String tipodep = "";
            int tipodec = 0; //variavel só para converter tipo


                for(int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
                //aqui pega somente o  primeiro dependente de todas as 
              //  pessoas e queria pegar de todos se existir e imprimir
                nomedep = vetor[i].substring(0,20);
                tipodep = vetor[i].substring(20,22);
                tipodec = Integer.parseInt(tipodep);
                System.out.println(nomedep +" "+ tipodec);
                }

        }
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `String.split(";");` para retornar um *array* como cada parte do texto. Assim você pode verificar se esse *array* possui o índice 2,3,4,5... e então captura-los. Ou pode utilizar *regex* para verificar se há dependentes e então usar o `String.split(";");` para capturar.

Comment: Agora que você editou a pergunta, esse código está muito estranho. `if(linha.length() > 36)` Isso não significa que há mais de 36 dependentes, e sim mais de 36 caracteres. Além disso você quer usar como separador o `";"` ou `"010203"`? Esse `tip` não tem nada a ver com nada. E depois, de onde vem os números 20 e 22?

Comment: os dados da pessoa ate dependente chega a 36 caracteres se existir mais são dependentes . e  o nome de dependente tem que ter 20 caracteres. e em vez de separar por(;) estou separando por tipo(01),(02)ou(03);

Comment: Isso me parece ser um [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Comment: estou conseguindo pegar apenas o primeiro dependente naquele ultimo for. Queria saber como pegar o restante se existir sabendo que só pode conter 20 caracteres e um tipo cada dependente

Answer (score 1):

Use o método [`split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) e depois retire o nome e a data de nascimento do começo:

```
String linha = /* ... */;

String[] partes = linha.split(";");
String nome = partes[0];
String strData = partes[1];

List<String> dependentes = Arrays.asList(partes);
dependentes = dependentes.subList(2, dependentes.size());

for (String dependente : dependentes) {
    // ...
}
```

Se esse ponto-e-vírgula após o último dependente sempre estiver ali, use `dependentes.size() - 1` ao invés de apenas `dependentes.size()`.